# Cramer rao lower bound gamma distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, estimation, parameter-estimation

I am interested in the estimator of the mean of the gamma distribution. I need to calculate the CRLB for this estimator. How can this be done, since the mean is $\kappa\theta$ (2 parameters). I consider the following possibilities:

1. Use the multivariate version of the CRLB. I think this is the right solution, but I am wondering if I can use the one-dimensional CRLB.
2. Consider one parameter constant. However, which one?
3. Substitute $\kappa\theta$ by for example $\mu$, since I want to estimate this parameter. However, then the likelihood will still be depending on 2 parameters, leading to idea 2. For example, I  substitute $\theta$ for $\frac{\mu}{\kappa}$ and need to assume $\kappa$ constant.

Hope you can give clear insight!

Thank you

Comment: Use the multivariate Cramer-Rao inequality: if $E_\theta T(X) = \tau(\theta)$, then $$\operatorname{var}_\theta(T)\ge (D_\theta \tau(\theta))^\top I^{-1}(\theta)D_\theta \tau(\theta),$$ where $D_\theta \tau(\theta)$ denotes the gradient (column) vector, and $I(\theta)$ is the Fisher information matrix.

Comment: @zhoraster This was indeed my guess, but is it possible to use a one-dimensional approach like 2 or 3?

Comment: Yes, using 3 is possible.

Comment: @zhoraster Does it matter how you choose the substitution then? ($\theta$ for $\frac{\mu}{\kappa}$ with $\kappa$ constant or $\kappa$ for $\frac{\mu}{\theta}$ with $\theta$ constant)

Comment: This should not matter as long as we do not speak of efficient estimators.

Comment: The question is in the context of UMVUE

Comment: Yes, "efficient estimator" = UMVUE. If you fix a parameter (say, $\kappa$), it might happen that the UMVUE depends on $\kappa$, so it won't work for the original problem. But these are only speculations, and there is only one way to find out the truth: you should sit and write everything down.